# How to make the overflow popup menu avoid obstructing the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-toolbar

### Background

On [**my app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), when I've updated to the new support library and also tried on Lollipop, I've noticed a weird issue: when clicking on the overflow button of the action bar (or even the new [**Toolbar**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) class) will show the popup menu on top of the action bar, hiding other action items, as such:

[image]

Here, the action items that got hidden are uninstallation and sharing.

### The problem

I've tried to avoid this issue, by ovverriding the style of the overflow menu, but nothing has helped.

Not only that, but it seems this is [**an intentional behavior**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-toolbars), yet in many Google apps that were updated to have Material design, this behavior doesn't hold, as I've reported [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1951).

### What I've tried

I've tried creating this in the theme I use . Actually my theme is very different and its parent is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" (and I use the Toolbar as the actionBar), but this snippet has this issue too, so I think that if one will be solved the other will too.

Anyway, here's the snippet:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionOverflowMenuStyle" tools:targetApi="21">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.PopupMenu.Overflow" tools:targetApi="21">
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">50dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Both attributes didn't change anything.

I've also tried looking for how it works in the support library, but couldn't find it.

### The question

How do I make the popup menu of the overflow action item to avoid hiding other item?

Comment: The Material theme (not the same as Material design) and AppCompat follow the standards laid out in the design documents. Specifically breaking the design guidelines isn't something either of those allow you to do.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please read all that I've written. That's something that even the material-design apps of Google doesn't do. Also, it causes other issues (which I've warned about) that other people have reported.

Comment: You can write a Material designed app without using AppCompat or the actual Material theme: those apps that **do** use AppCompat/Material theme only show popup menus overlaying the button.

Comment: Are you extending AppCompat for your app theme?

Comment: Also, side note, as the Android framework engineer who wrote the Material Design styles and themes, I can assure you that the default overlap behavior is correct.

Comment: @androiddeveloper `overlapAnchor` is what you're looking for. Try removing the `android` prefix before applying your `actionOverflowMenuStyle` and make sure you extend an `AppCompat` theme. 

See [`PopupWindow`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#L1178) and [`AppCompatPopupWindow`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/AppCompatPopupWindow.java#L48)

Comment: I dont understand the problem, you chose too open the overflow menu so why would you want the other item to be visible when you cannot interact with them anyway until you close the overflow menu

Comment: @alanv I've tried both the AppCompat theme and the Material theme. Both had those issues, and I've tried setting the attributes on both. What do you mean "the default overlap behavior is correct" ? Please explain why do you think it's better, as I've written multiple reasons for why it's wrong (on the post: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1951 ), and as I've expected, it causes accidental selections by users. Also, Google doesn't seem to follow this rule, so it does make sense to use the previous behavior.

Comment: @adneal That's the first guess I had, but maybe I was doing it wrong. Can you please post a sample that you've found to be working?

Comment: @tyczj See this post I've written for the reasons of why it's a problem: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1951 . Also search in the website for issues regarding the overflow menu. I've noticed at least one that describes the same problem as I've written (people accidentally choosing the first item).

Comment: Could you include a snippet of XML for your app theme? If you're targeting Material and using the built-in ActionBar, the XML that you've posted ought to work.

Comment: @alanv The theme is pretty large (and its parent is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" ) , so I've now made a tiny sample app to show this issue. updated the question. It occurs even for "Theme.AppCompat.Light" . If I solve it there, it will (I hope) work for my app too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using ActionBarActivity, you'll need to override the appcompat version of the overflow menu style along with the appcompat versions of the popup attributes, where applicable.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Guess I wasn't so far from the answer... :)

Comment: Unfortunately there's still a lot of guess-and-check required when overriding appcompat styles and themes. It should get easier in the future.

Comment: Say, is it also possible to set it at runtime?

Comment: No, but it's a property of PopupWindow which is wrapped several levels deep by PopupMenu and wouldn't be accessible anyway.

Comment: Too bad. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you get Target Api warning like: `android:overlapAnchor needs Api 21`, implement [this answer on so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18216531/284420)

Comment: This answer includes **verticalOffset** too which in my case was needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29468611/284420