# Android toolbar hidden items

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="10dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="10dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="10dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_36dp"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Reset App"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        >
    </item>
</menu>
```

How do I remove the white space to the right from hidden items? And how do I put them under the toolbar rather than on top of it?

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#888888</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

I've added this but it doesn't change nor fix anything. How can I change the layout of the hidden items in the toolbar? I've tried to look it up but I don't get it to work, and most posts are concerning hiding the toolbar rather than hidden items, so yeah, I'd like someone to explain it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to try this

Set the theme at android manifest to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

just look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738893/how-to-show-menu-popup-exact-below-actionbar) it will solve your problem

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Your Activity is extending ActionBarActivity which requires the AppCompat.theme to be applied. Change from ActionBarActivity to Activity or FragmentActivity, it will solve the problem.