# android actionbar menu overlapping on api 16

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I've one android with with minimun sdk 16
The app itself is working fine and i'm adjusting last visual details
I noticed that my action bar is not displaying properly on API 16

[image]

the left side is screenshot on api 16
the right side is screenshot on api 27

how can i make api 16 look like 27

Comment: You can try using a CustomMenu and then inflating it as a Popup. That will give you what you need.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738893/how-to-show-menu-popup-exact-below-actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738893/how-to-show-menu-popup-exact-below-actionbar)

Comment: what theme are you using

Comment: @KevinKurien `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 2):

This is the desired behaviour according to new design guidelines. You are using appCompat so it is supposed to happen. [see Menus](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html) - Component

Update: If you still don't want the overflow menu to overlap action bar, you will have to override overflow menu style from appCompat. This might work

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>
  <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
   <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dip</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

For Lollipop style must be in values-v21.

About the margin on the right I looked at many site only solution I could find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804589/change-the-margin-of-the-overflow-menu-in-android)  .
`<item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">-16dp</item>`
 
try changing the value to set it

Hope it helps

Comment: can you post your styles.xml

Comment: @RafaelLima i have edited my code try it and tell me what happens

Comment: it solves partially the problem... check result: https://imgur.com/ws4Vpwy

Comment: i had tried before `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset` changes nothing...