# How to lower the menu in the vertical position

Tags: android, material-design

The menu of my application appears as follows [image]and I need the menu items to appear just where in the limit of the action bar as it appears in the following image[image] Any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Two way to achieve that one use the custom style at v21

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
  <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
   <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dp</item>
  <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
   <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dp</item>
</style>
```

or use the android theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Reference [How I can place overflow menu below toolbar instead of overflow menu to overlaps the app bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445584/how-i-can-place-overflow-menu-below-toolbar-instead-of-overflow-menu-to-overlaps)

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `values/styles.xml` add `OverflowMenu` style as:

   ```
   <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
       <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
       <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4dp</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. In your `values-21/styles.xml` add `OverflowMenu` style as:

   ```
   <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
       <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
       <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4dp</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Finally, in your `values/styles.xml` main style use `OverflowMenu` style as `actionOverflowMenuStyle`.

**values/styles.xml**

```
    <resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

            <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
        </style>

        <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
            <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
            <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dp</item>

        </style>

    </resources>
```