# Overflow menu for appcompt theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am developing sample Android application in which I am trying to display menu items in the actionbar but it is always showing overflow menu in action bar tab and I want to display overflow menu below action bar. Please help me to solve these problem as I am using appcompt theme.

Here is my menu.xml

```
 <menu > 
  <item android:id="@+id/left_menu" 
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon" 
        app:showAsAction="always" 
        android:title="@string/left_menu"/> 

 <item android:id="@+id/profile" 
       android:icon="@drawable/user_icon" 
       app:showAsAction="always" 
       android:title="@string/profile"> 

<menu > 
  <item android:id="@+id/track_order" 
        android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" 
        android:title="@string/track_order"/> 


  <item android:id="@+id/rateApp" 
        android:icon="@drawable/user_icon" 
        app:showAsAction="never" android:title="@string/rate_app"/> 
</menu> 
</item> </menu>
```

Comment: Show your code and a screenshot of what you have / want to achieve.

Comment: <menu 
>
<item
android:id="@+id/left_menu"
android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/left_menu"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/profile"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
app:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/profile">
<menu >
<item
android:id="@+id/track_order"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
android:title="@string/track_order"/>
<item
android:id="@+id/rateApp"
android:icon="@drawable/user_icon"
app:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/rate_app"/>
</menu>
</item>
</menu>

Comment: and i want that overflow menu to be appear below action bar

Comment: Could you show a screenshot , and edit your question to put the code _in_ your question ? I believe there is a library called "Floating Action Button" to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979476/why-is-my-overflow-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-the-actionbar

Comment: above link will specify my problem ,but these problem is not still solved for appcompt theme

Comment: At that link, there is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27347498/4428462), which is for appcompat and should be what you want.

Comment: thanx it is working but not for above api level 21 .it show error android:overlapAnchor requires API level 21 (current min is 9)

Comment: Maybe try the bottom answer ?

Comment: it automatically appears on actionbar if proper style is applied. Post your styles.xml, Are u using Toolbar?

Comment: yes i am using tool bar

Comment: <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
    </style>

Comment: above code i have used in styles.xml

Comment: <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    </style>

Comment: above code works for both above api 21 and below api 21 .

Comment: but for below api 21 ,it shows some space from top and right between action bar and overflow menu

Comment: please help me to solve this