# How to add theme to Android ActionMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I am following [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979476) about changing the appearance of the Action overflow menu, and it tells me to create a theme to create the desired changes.

I know how to create a theme, and I know how to apply a theme to the whole application or a specific activity, but I don't understand how to apply a theme specifically to the ActionBar / Action Overflow Menu.

From the accepted answer of the above mentioned S.O. post, I've created this theme.  Could someone help me understand how to apply it to the ActionBar / Action Overflow menu?

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow" >
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a whole new theme, overriding only the part you have interest in modifying.
Assuming the parent theme of your app is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar":

```
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <!--Your custom ActionBar items-->
    </style>

   <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow" >
       <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
       <item name="dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item> 
   </style>
```

Then you apply this theme in the Android Manifest to the whole app or to the single activities, adding the line:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```