# Android toolbar overflow menu dropdwon

Tags: android

Hi I have an toolbar with overflow menu like below, Overflow menu is not coming as a dropdown, I mean it should come below toolbar, how can i do it..?

[image]

Expected Overflow menu like below, Overflow menu top attached to toolbar

[image]

Comment: How is it coming then?

Comment: @Boss : Dropdown should come as its top attached to toolbar

Comment: Yeah. You are getting something different right? Or are you not getting anything??

Comment: Am getting overflow dorpdown like above attached image, its coming on top of toolbar, it should come below toolbar

Comment: No. Its exactly how it should come. There is no problem. Its how its coming in material design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior in Material theme. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979476/why-is-my-overflow-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-the-actionbar) is short explanation how to put it below and why you should **not** put it below the `Toolbar`.