# How to make my menu to appear below the Action Bar area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

My Question is how i can move my menu dropdown to the space with pink area(see second image).As if now it is appearing in the Action Bar area too that i don't want.I want my menu to be appear just below the Action bar.

Please guys help me out to solve this situation.

[image]

This is how menu is coming.

[image]

I want my menu to appear just below the Action Bar.

This is how my menu.xml looks like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.mobileinventorysuit.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/login_mnu_imports"
        android:icon="@drawable/import_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        style="@style/OverflowMenu"
        android:title="Import"/> 
   <item
        android:id="@+id/login_mnu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_menu"
        style="@style/OverflowMenu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Settings"/>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/login_mnu_dev"
        android:icon="@drawable/dev"
        style="@style/OverflowMenu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Device Info"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/login_mnu_exit"
        style="@style/OverflowMenu"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
        android:title="Exit"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: You can make a new xml layout fro menu. Then you can include that layout in the currnet main xml. Set it to hidden first. Add a button or any image view adn upon clicking on that view display your menu. I ahve done it many items.

Comment: Can you please send me some links or reference as i'm little new bee to it...that will be helpful for me. @Raj Sharma

Comment: this link would be helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979476/why-is-my-overflow-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-the-actionbar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the `ActionBar` menu should display on top of the action bar.
From the [Documentation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)

> A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the app bar,
>   rather than behaving as an extension of the app bar.

If you still want that behaviour you can use this. But its not recommended.

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow" >
         <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
         <item name="dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

Check this answer [Why is my overflow dropdown menu on top of the actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979476/why-is-my-overflow-dropdown-menu-on-top-of-the-actionbar)

### EDIT

If you want icons placed in your `ToolBar`

add this in `menu.xml`

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and add this line in your menuitems

```
 app:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: The reference that you have mentioned clear my whole doubts...Thanks

Comment: I'm also trying to display icons in my menu but doesn't appears...Do you know why?@ Boss

Comment: I tried it but i can't see any icons befor menuItem @ Boss

Comment: You want an icon with the menu item or just an icon in the actionbar??

Comment: before menu items @ Boss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87743/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-boss).

Answer (score 1):

Go to res => values => styles and add those two lines I indicated in the comment below.It will help you

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

     //add these two line scripts and it will work properly

    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code only answers are generally not accepted. Always try to explain your solution and why this adds something to the current answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this in `PopUpWindow`:

```
   mWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, getScreenWidth((Activity) mContext) - getPixelFromDp(mContext, 465), getPixelFromDp(mContext, 0));

  public static int getScreenWidth(Activity context){
     Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     return display.getWidth();
  }

   public static int getPixelFromDp(Context context, int dpUnits) {
      float pixel = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpUnits, getDisplayMetrics(context));
      return (int) pixel;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is correct**

```
  <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
```